# Any suggestions when it shows " TypeError: not enough arguments for format string " in Python?

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

when I try to run an example of Matrix multiplication by pycuda.

```
kernel_code_template = """
__global__ void MatrixMulKernel(float *a,float *b,float *c){
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;
    float Pvalue = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<%(N)s; ++i){
        float Aelement = a[ty * %(N)s + i];
        float Belement = b[i * %(M)s + tx];
        Pvalue += Aelement * Belement;
    }
    c[ty * %[M]s + tx] = Pvalue;
}
"""

M, N = 2, 3
kernel_code = kernel_code_template % {'M': M, 'N': N}
```

it reported error like:

```
kernel_code = kernel_code_template % {'M': M, 'N': N}
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I've tried to check if there is anything wrong with "%" mark but got nothing yet.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: it's 3.7 @Thomas

Comment: Cheers, added my answer.

Comment: " %[M]s" -- you have a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer the question, you need to change `%[M]s` to `%(M)s` in your code, like so:

```py
kernel_code_template = """
__global__ void MatrixMulKernel(float *a,float *b,float *c){
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;
    float Pvalue = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<%(N)s; ++i){
        float Aelement = a[ty * %(N)s + i];
        float Belement = b[i * %(M)s + tx];
        Pvalue += Aelement * Belement;
    }
    c[ty * %(M)s + tx] = Pvalue;
}
"""
```

Then it will work as expected. However, I'd strongly recommend you start using f-strings as you indicated you were working with Python 3.7:

```py
kernel_code_template = f"""
__global__ void MatrixMulKernel(float *a,float *b,float *c){{
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y;
    float Pvalue = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<{N}; ++i){{
        float Aelement = a[ty * {N} + i];
        float Belement = b[i * {M} + tx];
        Pvalue += Aelement * Belement;
    }}
    c[ty * {M} + tx] = Pvalue;
}}
"""
```

I get there are trade-offs, though, namely those `{{` and `}}` escapes. There is also the `.format()` method as @Brandt pointed out. Choose what feels best to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot ！it works perfectly and it‘s so nice of you all ! And there is one more thing, that in the second method ( which uses {M} and {N} ) , the line 'M, N = 2, 3'  have to be write before the kernel or it would report M&N as "undefine". This is interesting and I guess it's because computers need to allocate space in CPU and GPU respectively.    @Thomas

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped you, feel free to leave an upvote and/or accept the answer. As for the comment on CPU and GPU, it's because M and N aren't defined symbols in your code until they are explicitly assigned so it has more to do with memory used by the process; you could run this code snippet on a computer without a GPU!

Answer (score 1):

<s>I think you are mixing syntaxes, `%` with `.format` string substituions. Check here for a nice summary:</s> https://pyformat.info/

Now I spot the error (line 11): `%[M]s` --> `%(M)s`

Comment: sry , I haven't seen till now  @Brandt